# How to get LDAP nested groups from attribute

Tags: c#, ldap, ldap-query

I can search the user and find only the groups that the user belongs to. And now i want to return all the groups/roles and assign a user to a specific group/role.

DirectoryEntry and PrincipalContext doesn't work in my case and i have tried that for days.

This is my working code for searching user group/roles which is working fine.

1. How can i get all the groups/roles?
2. And Add user to a group/role

```
Container  = “ou=containername,ou=xx,ou=xx,O=xxxxx”
Domain = “mydomain.com” 
group = ou=groups,ou=containername,ou=xx,ou=xx,O=xxxx
```

[image]

```
List<string> roles = new List<string>();

SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("", "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=myusername))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)con.SendRequest(request);

if (response.Entries.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Attributes["member"] != null)
        {
            roles = (entry.Attributes["member"].GetValues(typeof(string))).ToArray().Select(r => r.ToString()
                    .Substring(r.ToString().IndexOf("cn=") + 3,
                     r.ToString().IndexOf(",") - 3))
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
}
return roles;
```

Comment: Are you using Active Directory, or a different LDAP provider?

Comment: I am using LDAP("LDAP://"). connection is already being established and hence i am able to get roles/groups linked to a particular user.

Comment: Right, but what is the server? Active Directory, OpenLDAP, etc.? I ask because AD has its own quirks compared to other LDAP servers.

Comment: It is a private LDAP(companies LDAP) xxxxxxxx.com:636 I am not sure if i have answered you on you question.

Comment: No :) LDAP is just a protocol - a "language" of communicating. I'm wondering what software is on the server. But that's ok. I'll try to answer as best as I can.

Comment: my bad, which means i didn't understand your question. I think they have used Java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197307/discussion-between-it-forward-and-gabriel-luci).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're using Active Directory. What tipped me off is that you're getting data from the `member` attribute of a user. That's not how it works with Active Directory (it would be `memberOf`).

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. Your title mentioned "nested groups", which means when one group is a member of another group. So I assume that would mean that you want to find every group the user is a member of and all groups that those groups are members of, etc. If that's the case, you will really have to find out what type of server you're connecting to before anyone can give you a good answer on that.

But in your question you say "How can i get all the groups/roles?" So does that mean you just want to find every group that exists? To do that, you can just do a new search and use this as the filter:

```
(objectClass=group)
```

For adding a user to a group, I think it would be something like this (where `userDn` is the `distinguishedName` of the user you want to add, and `groupDn` is that of the group):

```
var mod = new DirectoryAttributeModification {
    Name = "member",
    Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Add
}
mod.Add(userDn);

var response = (ModifyResponse) connectionObject.SendRequest(
    new ModifyRequest {
        DistinguishedName = groupDn,
        Modifications = { mod }
    }
);
```

But I've never actually used `LdapConnection`, so you might need to tweak it.

Comment: I am also using LDAP connection. I have added my add function but am now getting this error "The distinguished name contains invalid syntax." Also for getting all the group i have created new search but nothing returning. Please advise

//SearchRequest sendRequest = new SearchRequest("", "(&(objectClass=group))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
                //SearchResponse sendResponse = (SearchResponse)con.SendRequest(sendRequest);

Comment: "The distinguished name contains invalid syntax." means that one of the distinguished names you are giving it (for the user or group) doesn't match what is in the directory.

Comment: For searching groups, you can try `(objectCategory=group)`. It really depends on how the LDAP server is setup.

Comment: Thanks, now it looks like am heading to the right direction. the problem was on group name. now am getting this error "An object class violation occurred."  on _response function

Comment: Sounds like it's an OpenLDAP server. I don't have much experience there. I did a quick search and it might because the wrong attribute is being set? It's possible that `member` isn't the right attribute. It might be `memberUid`. If not, you'll have to ask the server admins which attribute is used on groups for the membership.

Comment: That's correct, i was passing the wrong attribute name. I have pass the correct one and it doesn't throw and error. But when i query it from client i don't get added role.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ADLDS or AD MemberOf (User object) Member (Group object) attribute is not retrieved.

Example Solution for User

```c#
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("", "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=myusername))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);

request.Attributes.Add("memberOf");
```

or Group

```c#
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("", "(&(objectClass=group))", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);

request.Attributes.Add("member");
```

[Default LDAP Filters and Attributes for Users, Groups and Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26214/html/ldap-filters-attrs-users.html#ldap-filters-attributes-users-default)